# Laravel Excel Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm having to use `DB::select` instead of calling a Model because my data structure is too complex.

My main SQL query is;

```
    /* main mysql query */
    $sql = "SELECT t1.* FROM `contracts`.`payments` as t1 LEFT JOIN `postcodes`.`" . $postcode_dataset . "` AS t2 ON t1.`VendorZIP` = t2.`postcode` WHERE "; 

    foreach ($unserialized_input as $key => $value) {
        $sql .= "t2." . $key . " IN ('".implode("', '", $unserialized_input[$key])."') OR ";
    }

    $sql = rtrim($sql, " OR ");

    $payments = DB::select($sql);
```

I am trying to use Maatwebsite Excel to export the result by doing this;

```
Excel::create('SME_Payments_Export-U', function($excel) use ($payments) {

        $excel->sheet('Excel sheet', function($sheet) use ($payments) {

            $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');
            $sheet->fromArray($payments);

        });

    })->export('csv');
```

But I get the error;

```
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Here is a sample of my var_dump;

```
array(176) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#302 (4) {
    ["Fiscal Year"]=>
    string(5) "13/14"
    ["Contract Number"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Foreign Ind"]=>
    string(1) "N"
    ["Valued or Running"]=>
    string(1) "R"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#304 (4) {
    ["Fiscal Year"]=>
    string(5) "13/14"
    ["Contract Number"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Foreign Ind"]=>
    string(1) "Y"
    ["Valued or Running"]=>
    string(1) "V"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#305 (4) {
    ["Fiscal Year"]=>
    string(5) "13/14"
    ["Contract Number"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Foreign Ind"]=>
    string(1) "N"
    ["Valued or Running"]=>
    string(1) "R"
  }
```

How can I convert `payments`?

Comment: use http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries to select data from db and use `toArray()` method..

Comment: That wont work as I'm creating a query that used two databases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export) you need to transform array of objects to array of arrays before passing it to `fromArray()` method:

```
foreach ($payments as &$payment) {
    $payment = (array)$payment;
}

$sheet->fromArray($payments);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced same problem and what worked for me best is:

```
$payments = json_decode( json_encode($payments), true);
```

This will convert object/array to array and make it usable.